# Storage Size increases after deleteMany() in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, storage, wiredtiger

I deleted ~4 million documents from a MongoDB collection. Resulting Stats which I noticed were a bit shocking.

Original DB Stats :-

DataSize - 20GB
StorageSize - 6.6GB
Available for reuse - 2MB
TotalIndexSize - 3.24GB

After deleteMany() Stats :-

DataSize - 0.24GB
StorageSize - 8.6GB
Available for reuse - 8.5GB
TotalIndexSize - 6.29GB

I understand that mongoDB does not give up storage size after delete, you need to perform further operations like repair database, compact etc on it. But in my scenario storage size does not remain the same, it increases.

Note - Storage engine used is wired tiger.

Can anyone explain why is this happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Try ([source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/storage/#faq-disk-size)):

> $ mongo mydb
>
> db.repairDatabase()